# can i compare 3 columns parallely in spark from two different dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I have two dataframes a) metadata --with SAS dataformat

```
 metadata.show
+----+----------------+----+---+-----------+-----------+
|S_No|        Variable|Type|Len|     Format|   Informat|
+----+----------------+----+---+-----------+-----------+
|   1|        DATETIME| Num|  8|DATETIME20.|DATETIME20.|
|   2|   LOAD_DATETIME| Num|  8|DATETIME20.|DATETIME20.|
|   3|     SOURCE_BANK|Char|  1|           |       null|
|   4|        EMP_NAME|Char| 50|           |       null|
|   5|HEADER_ROW_COUNT| Num|  8|           |       null|
|   6|       EMP_HOURS| Num|  8|       15.2|       15.1|
+----+----------------+----+---+-----------+-----------+

and second containing hive dataformat
scala> df2.show
+----------------+-------------+
|        Variable|         type|
+----------------+-------------+
|        datetime|TimestampType|
|   load_datetime|TimestampType|
|     source_bank|   StringType|
|        emp_name|   StringType|
|header_row_count|  IntegerType|
|       emp_hours|   DoubleType|
+----------------+-------------+
```

Now, I need to validate metadata with df2 , if `timestamptype` validates with type `Num`  &format `Datetime` in `SAS` the result should be true. else case should return false. similarly for all types.

Can any one help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you tell us the output you expect?

Comment: Exact output should be "true" if structure validations passes. e.g.if "DATETIME"in metadata show has type as "Num"& format as "DATETIME20" and it matches with "timestamptype "in df2 output should return as true. In same way for all columns